# How do I fix the NoReverseMatch Django error?

Tags: django, url, view, cs50

I am trying to complete a CS50 Project, I want to render a HTML page, the template is in respective ***templates/encyclopedia*** directory.

The error page for url `127.0.0.1:8000/wiki/HTML` says NoReverseMatch at wiki/HTML.
Reverse for 'edit' not found. 'edit' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

The responsible **URLS.py** are `"wiki/<str:search>"` and `"wiki/random"`.

**I'm sorry but I don't want to post this long code here but I am stuck at this problem for weeks now.
I have tried many ways don't know what's wrong with this code.**

The below is my URLS.py, the projects index url includes the below urls:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("wiki/newpage", views.newpage, name="newpage"),
    # path("wiki/<str:edit>/edit", views.edit, name="edit"),
    path("wiki/random", views.random, name="random"),
    path("wiki/<str:search>", views.search, name="search"),
    path("wiki/", views.find, name="find")
]
```

The below is my VIEWS.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
import markdown2 as md
from . import util
from django import forms
import re, random as rand

def index(request):
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/index.html", {
        "entries": util.list_entries()
    })

def search(request, search):
    if search in util.list_entries():
        html = md.markdown(util.get_entry(search))
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/search.html", {
            "search": search, "html": html
        })
    else:
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/error.html")

def random(request):
    randomPage = rand.choice(util.list_entries())
    if randomPage in util.list_entries():
        html = md.markdown(util.get_entry(randomPage))
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/search.html", {
            "random": randomPage, "html": html
        })
    else:
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/error.html")

def find(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        query = request.GET.get('q')
        for queryMatch in util.list_entries():
            if query.casefold() == queryMatch.casefold():
                html = md.markdown(util.get_entry(query))
                return render(request, "encyclopedia/search.html", {
                    "queryMatch": queryMatch, "html": html
                })
        regex = re.compile(query.casefold())
        matchList = []
        for a in util.list_entries():
            if regex.match(a.casefold()):
                matchList.append(a)
        if not matchList:
            matchList = util.list_entries()
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/list.html", {
            "match": matchList
        })

class NewPageForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(label="Title")
    content = forms.CharField(label="Markdown Content", widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols': '100'}))

def newpage(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = NewPageForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            title = form.cleaned_data["title"]
            content = form.cleaned_data["content"]
            if title in util.list_entries():
                messages.error(request, f"'{title}' page title already exists!!\nPlease type another title.")
                return render(request, "encyclopedia/newpage.html", {
                    "form": form
                })
            else:
                util.save_entry(title, content)
                return redirect(f"/wiki/{title}")
        else:
            return render(request, "encyclopedia/newpage.html", {
                "form": form
            })
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/newpage.html", {
        "form": NewPageForm()
    })

# def edit(request, edit):
#     entry = util.get_entry(edit)
```

Comment: Which Django version? Url with name 'find' is working?

Comment: @NKSM no it's not working and showing the same error.

Comment: What is your project directory structure? Have you include your app.urls in project.urls?

Answer (score 0):

Have you include your `app.urls` in `project.urls`?

[Including other URLconfs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs)

Some example from Django tutorial:

**polls/urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

**mysite/urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Comment: Is this a rhetorical question? :)

Comment: @Scratte, time will tell :)

Comment: @NKSM yes I have included my app URLs.py in my project.